# Would I need a database for this Android app idea?

Tags: android, sql, database

I have already created 1 Android app. Was very basic, basically a button that goes to a new instance that contains a link to a website.

My question is regarding a idea for my next app. My intent is to be able to search for information on a item. Example, I have a cabinet full of items. I open my app search for a item and it tells me where it is located in the cabinet.

Of course I need to populate all the information on where items are located in the cabinet. My question is what would be the best way to accomplish this. Do I need to setup a SQL database? If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great! Also, does anyone know of a good community/forum for Android development?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make searches, and depending the kind and the complexity of the searches, it would be a good idea to use a database (you can always manage a datastructure if there is little and basic information), over a SQLite for example. Also, if the data is going to change, it would be a good idea to make a webapp (which will have a database), and the Android app establish a connection with the webapp (like a RIA) so it can get the data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many items and how much information you need for each item. You could use a data structure to store the information but if its a lot of information and a lot of searching is going to be happening then it would be much faster to use a database.